How can I fix xhci on kubuntu 22.04.3?
I had this fixed for a while when I was running Kubuntu 20.04.5, but after replacing a failed Gigabyte 970A-DS3P motherboard and upgrading to 22.04.1 (August or September 2022) and ever since, I get the following during startup:

[    1.951985] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller


[    1.951997] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8


[    1.952050] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 > address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952079] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952092] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952107] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952120] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952133] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952147] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952160] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952173] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    1.952185] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952562] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952597] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952629] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952660] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952692] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952752] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952783] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952814] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952845] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[    6.952876] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956563] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956599] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956631] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956662] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956694] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956725] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956756] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956787] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956818] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   11.956877] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960563] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960598] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960630] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960661] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960693] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960724] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.960755] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.961134] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.961471] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   16.961795] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0010 address=0xbe9c6880 flags=0x0000]


[   19.516501] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: can't setup: -110


[   19.634553] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: USB bus 8 deregistered


[   19.634994] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: init 0000:02:00.0 fail, -110


[   19.635439] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110

Along with this, of course, my USB 3.0 ports don't work -- I can't even charge my phone from one.
I'm now running a Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P with Kubuntu 22.04.4 and HWE kernel 6.5.0-28-generic, kept up to date (this has occurred with multiple kernels, both before and after I installed the HWE stack).  I've tried disabling and enabling Legacy USB support and XHCI handoff in my UEFI settings, without improvement.
I'd like to get rid of these error messages and regain use of my USB 3.0 ports.  How?
